# Android Studio - Username not appear on phpmyadmin registration table

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

i'm trying to create a registration and login app. But i got an error on phpmyadmin. The **username var not appear inside the table column**. It looks like this[Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zZE8.png)

This is the code. Tell me if you want to see more of the code. Could you guys help me ?

Register.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("--", "--", "--", "--");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });

}
}
```

RegisterRequest.java

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://gen7utsu.coolpage.biz/register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null );
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("age", age + "");
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Comment: We will be glad to help but no superpowers until we see your code. By the way, are you sure you are including the username field while saving from your PHP side of things?

Comment: there you go, i already checked the code again and again and still get noting about the error in the code. Thanks. @saopayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code `"siss", $name, $username, $age, $password`

and `public RegisterRequest(String name, String username`

`username` is a string and not an integer, where you are using `i` rather than `s` in your binding.

You may have inadvertently reversed the `i` with the `s`.

and meant to use: `"ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password` since `age` appears to be an integer.

Make sure the column's type matches being `VARCHAR` and is of the correct length.

If your "username" column is an `INT` or similar integer-based column, then you're trying to enter a string into an integer-based column which won't work.

Check for errors against your query, you're not doing that.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Other links of interest:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)